# PDF security problem

Tags: windows, security, pdf, okular, document-management

I'm looking for a program that allows me to export a document to PDF safely, so that other users can open it but can not copy or print its contents.

While I used Windows I used PDF printers such as PDF24 and BullZip, which allowed me to create documents with these characteristics. But when I opened these documents from my Ubuntu with Okular or Document Viewer, all safety features disappeared. So, I could copy and print documents protected by Windows on Ubuntu.

My question then is: how I can protect PDFs on all platforms? I'm looking for something easy to use because it will be used by people who have NO extensive knowledge in computers.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried CutePDF ?
 
From their documentation, the paid version seems to be able to set security policies, such as password protection and print protection

Answer (score 0):

Try using [pdfTweak](http://jpdftweak.sourceforge.net/). It permits encrypting pdf files amongst other functionality.

Alternatively, you may use pdftk.